# What do the JSON objects look like if sent through URL

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am currently using AJAX to send a JSON object to a Handler written in C#. I was wondering if I can pass the JSON information through a simple url for debugging purposes, just like when I used to use simple parameters (queries) on URLs.

The C# handler deserializes the JSON into a class based on Name and Pass (strings).

So I am trying to go to the handler on the URL like this:

```
testHandler.ashx?Name=Hey&Pass=Check
```

Though the C# handler cannot deserialize that properly and the class object is null, if sent that way.

AJAX code of sending a working request to the web server:

```
var jsonParam = { Name: "test", Pass: "123" }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Test.ashx",
            type: "post", //This sends in url
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonParam),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async:false,
            success: function (response) { 
                alert(response.Name);
            }
        });
```

So I am wondering what this would look like, if sent through the browser on the URL text box.

P.S - I don't have a problem, I'm just trying to understand the work behind the serialization.

Comment: Show your ajax sending code please so we can see what/how you are sending to the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 AJAX code added

Comment: I would look into using a web debugging tool (such as Fiddler2).  You will be able to see what exactly you are sending with your ajax requests, which should be useful in debuging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sample code you provided you are using JSON object serialized in the body of a POST request. Then you seem to be talking about some `testHandler.ashx?Name=Hey&Pass=Check` url where you are illustrating the values being passed as query string parameters. There's no longer JSON involved in this case. You should not be passing JSON payloads as parts of the query string. This is a perfectly valid request that you could achieve with the GET verb:

```
var jsonParam = { Name: "test", Pass: "123" }
$.ajax({
    url: "Test.ashx",
    type: "GET",
    data: jsonParam,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) { 
        alert(response.Name);
    }
});
```

In this case you will obviously retrieve the values directly from the query string of course instead of doing any JSON deserialization in your handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string name = context.Request["Name"];
    string pass = context.Request["Pass"];

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    ...
}
```

Oh and by the way notice that I have removed the `async: false` switch from your code coz everytime I see this it makes me vomit.

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me now! From what I read, I thought I have to deserialize everything into C# classes which means turn my handlers way larger. Thanks to you I now understand that all I needed was to return JSON objects, not to receive them so. Thank you so much!